# Fill DataGridView with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, datagridview

I want to populate my DataGridView with data from MySql.
I am using Nhibernate to configure it. I configured it and created the session.

```
using (var session = sessionf.OpenSession()) //open session
 {
   var dealers = session.QueryOver<Dealer>().List(); //Query to get the dealers

   //please help me what to do after this.
   }
```

How do I bind data to my datagridview?
Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be too late, but maybe it can be helpful to others in the future.
As @Andres suggest, but giving a more complete answer, the solution is the following, use the Datasource property from the dataGridView class, as you can see below:

```
using (var session = sessionf.OpenSession()) //open session
{
     var dealers = session.QueryOver<Dealer>().List(); //Query to get the dealers

     dataGridView1.DataSource = dealers; // <- Code you are asking for

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest might you fill  the datagridview with DATASOURCE property, for example 
Datagridview.datasource = delers

greetings